# "AND" operator in CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

I'm pretty familiar with xpath but not so much using css selectors in order to find a certain element.

I know this xpath `//input[contains(@value, "15.02.2022")` would result into this css-selector `input[value*="15.02.2022"]`.

But how would you translate this xpath `//input[contains(@value, "15.02.2022") and contains(@value, "123")]` into a css selector?

How would you use the "AND" operator to find a certain element?

Comment: Chain the selectors together: `input[value*="15.02.2022"][value*="123"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you aren't restricted to only one selector of a kind (with the notable exception of element selectors, for obvious reasons):

```css
.a.b {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<span class="a">Only A</span>
<span class="b">Only B</span>
<span class="a b">Both A and B</span>
```

Attribute selectors work the same way:

```css
input[value*="15.02.2022"][value*="123"] {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<input value="Only 15.02.2022">
<input value="Only 123">
<input value="Both 15.02.2022 and 123">
```